# Is this correct usage of a colon?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, colons

I'm fairly terrible at English, is this correct usage of a colon?

> Bigotry unfortunately doesn’t just relate to opinions: it refers to
>   intolerance towards ethnicities and beliefs

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure you're perfectly good at English: it is, after all, (I assume) your own language. Whether or not you know all the arcane and often arbitrary rules of fashion called punctuation is quite a different matter. These are important socially, just like knowing how to dress appropriately for the occasion; but say nothing about your competence in English.

Answer (score 1):

A *semicolon* is more appropriate here.

For the usage of colons [this article](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp) is excellent.

For the usage of semicolons refer to [this article](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html).

You will find that the main theme is that colons are used to define what is before it, and semicolons are used to connect related ideas.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion: I could argue that, in the cited sentence, *"it refers to intolerance towards ethnicities and beliefs"* is defining / amplifying *"what is before it"*.  I may well have used a semicolon there.

Comment: Your link takes us to Jane Staus' *Blue Book of Grammar and Usage*, where we find this -- "Colons and semicolons should never be used interchangeably." But the *Chicago Manual of Style* notes that contemporary usage prefers that semicolons or periods separate definitional or exemplifying  clauses.  Pick your style manual; pick your style.

Answer (score 1):

As punctuation is a matter of style, not grammar or usage, *correct* must be understood relative to the manual of style that you're using.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which notes that a colon may be used to separate two clauses when the second clause provides an "illustration or amplification" of the first. Which seems to apply to your sentence.